# TensorFlow: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow, apache-beam, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

Let's say I have this data frame saved in a parquet format

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], 
    b=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.NaN, 0.0, np.NaN],
    c=[0.9, np.NaN, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
))

data.to_parquet('data.parquet')
```

along with a dictionary that tells me which values I should use for the imputation. Then I can write a preprocessing function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

impute_dictionary = dict(b=1.0, c=0.0)

def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    outputs = inputs.copy()

    for key, value in impute_dictionary.items():
        outputs[key] = tf.where(
            tf.math.is_nan(outputs[key]),
            tf.constant(value, shape=outputs[key].shape),
            outputs[key]
        )

    return outputs
```

and use it in Apache Beam pipeline

```
import tempfile

import apache_beam as beam
import tensorflow_transform.beam as tft_beam
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata, schema_utils

temp = tempfile.gettempdir()

RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC = dict(
    [(name, tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)) for name in ['a', 'b', 'c']] 
)

RAW_DATA_METADATA = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(schema_utils.schema_from_feature_spec(RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC))

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    with tft_beam.Context(temp_dir=tempfile.mkdtemp()):
        raw_data = pipeline | 'ReadTrainData' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet('data.parquet')
        raw_dataset = (raw_data, RAW_DATA_METADATA)
        transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (raw_dataset | tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(preprocessing_fn))
        transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset
        transformed_data_coder = tft.coders.ExampleProtoCoder(transformed_metadata.schema)
```

I get this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

It seems that `outputs[key].shape` is `(None,)`

Any suggestion?

Package versions:

```
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-transform==0.21.0
pandas==1.0.0
numpy==1.18.1
apache-beam==2.19.0
```

Entire error message:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0204 10:36:03.793034 140735593104256 interactive_environment.py:113] Dependencies required for Interactive Beam PCollection visualization are not available, please use: `pip install apache-beam[interactive]` to install necessary dependencies to enable all data visualization features.
W0204 10:36:03.793169 140735593104256 interactive_environment.py:125] You have limited Interactive Beam features since your ipython kernel is not connected any notebook frontend.
W0204 10:36:03.929135 140735593104256 impl.py:360] Tensorflow version (2.1.0) found. Note that Tensorflow Transform support for TF 2.0 is currently in beta, and features such as tf.function may not work as intended. 
W0204 10:36:03.929914 140735593104256 impl.py:360] Tensorflow version (2.1.0) found. Note that Tensorflow Transform support for TF 2.0 is currently in beta, and features such as tf.function may not work as intended. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-465b3f61784c> in <module>
     17         raw_data = pipeline | 'ReadTrainData' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet('data.parquet')
     18         raw_dataset = (raw_data, RAW_DATA_METADATA)
---> 19         transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (raw_dataset | tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(preprocessing_fn))
     20         transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset
     21         transformed_data_coder = tft.coders.ExampleProtoCoder(transformed_metadata.schema)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in __ror__(self, left, label)
    547     pvalueish = _SetInputPValues().visit(pvalueish, replacements)
    548     self.pipeline = p
--> 549     result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
    550     if deferred:
    551       return result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575       transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    576 
--> 577     pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    578 
    579     if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    193       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    194       if m:
--> 195         return m(transform, input, options)
    196     raise NotImplementedError(
    197         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    223   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    224     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 225     return transform.expand(input)
    226 
    227   def run_transform(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_transform/beam/impl.py in expand(self, dataset)
    861     # e.g. caching the values of expensive computations done in AnalyzeDataset.
    862     transform_fn = (
--> 863         dataset | 'AnalyzeDataset' >> AnalyzeDataset(self._preprocessing_fn))
    864 
    865     if Context.get_use_deep_copy_optimization():

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in __ror__(self, pvalueish, _unused)
    987 
    988   def __ror__(self, pvalueish, _unused=None):
--> 989     return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)
    990 
    991   def expand(self, pvalue):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py in __ror__(self, left, label)
    547     pvalueish = _SetInputPValues().visit(pvalueish, replacements)
    548     self.pipeline = p
--> 549     result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
    550     if deferred:
    551       return result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    534       try:
    535         old_label, transform.label = transform.label, label
--> 536         return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
    537       finally:
    538         transform.label = old_label

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py in apply(self, transform, pvalueish, label)
    575       transform.type_check_inputs(pvalueish)
    576 
--> 577     pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
    578 
    579     if type_options is not None and type_options.pipeline_type_check:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply(self, transform, input, options)
    193       m = getattr(self, 'apply_%s' % cls.__name__, None)
    194       if m:
--> 195         return m(transform, input, options)
    196     raise NotImplementedError(
    197         'Execution of [%s] not implemented in runner %s.' % (transform, self))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py in apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options)
    223   def apply_PTransform(self, transform, input, options):
    224     # The base case of apply is to call the transform's expand.
--> 225     return transform.expand(input)
    226 
    227   def run_transform(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_transform/beam/impl.py in expand(self, dataset)
    808     input_values, input_metadata = dataset
    809     result, cache = super(AnalyzeDataset, self).expand((input_values, None,
--> 810                                                         None, input_metadata))
    811     assert not cache
    812     return result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_transform/beam/impl.py in expand(self, dataset)
    681         copied_inputs = impl_helper.copy_tensors(input_signature)
    682 
--> 683       output_signature = self._preprocessing_fn(copied_inputs)
    684 
    685     # At this point we check that the preprocessing_fn has at least one

<ipython-input-2-205d9abf4136> in preprocessing_fn(inputs)
      9         outputs[key] = tf.where(
     10             tf.math.is_nan(outputs[key]),
---> 11             tf.constant(value, shape=outputs[key].shape),
     12             outputs[key]
     13         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    256   """
    257   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 258                         allow_broadcast=True)
    259 
    260 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    294       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    295           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 296           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    297   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    298   const_tensor = g._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    446     # If shape is None, numpy.prod returns None when dtype is not set, but
    447     # raises exception when dtype is set to np.int64
--> 448     if shape is not None and np.prod(shape, dtype=np.int64) == 0:
    449       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)
    450     else:

<__array_function__ internals> in prod(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2960     """
   2961     return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
-> 2962                           keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
   2963 
   2964 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     88                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     89 
---> 90     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     91 
     92 

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: @AMC I've shared it. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that I set the shape in `tf.constant(value, shape=outputs[key].shape)`. I should have only used `tf.constant(value, dtype=tf.float32)`.